# Show that $11^{n+1}+12^{2n-1}$ is divisible by $133$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

Problem taken from a [paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/23a_fall_05/Handouts/induction.pdf) on mathematical induction by Gerardo Con Diaz. Although it doesn't look like anything special, I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to crack this, with no luck. Most likely, due to the late hour, I am missing something very trivial here.

> Prove that for any integer $n$, the number $11^{n+1}+12^{2n-1}$ is divisible by $133$.

I have tried multiplying through by $12$ and rearranging, but like I said with meager results. I arrived at $11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}$ which satisfies the induction hypothesis for LHS, but for the RHS I got stuck at $12 \times 133m-11^{n+1}-11^{n+3}$ or $12^2 \times 133m-12 \times11^{n+1}-11^{n+3}$ and several other combinations none of which would let me factor out $133$.

Comment: Answers below are great, but isn't this proof formulated incorrectly? This is only true for the natural numbers, not integers, since $11 + 12^{-1} < 133$

Comment: @Dancrumb I've copied the problem 'as is' from the paper, but it does indeed seem that what the author meant was "for any _positive_ integer", so you're right!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

$$11^{(n+1)+1} + 12^{2(n+1)-1} = 11 \cdot 11^{n+1} + 144 \cdot 12^{2n-1} = 11 \left(11^{n+1} + 12^{2n-1}\right) + 133 \cdot 12^{2n-1}$$

---

- $11 \left(11^{n+1} + 12^{2n-1}\right)$ is divisible by 133 by the induction hypothesis.
- $133 \cdot 12^{2n-1}$ is clearly a multiple of $133$.

Answer (score 18):

In fact, we can prove a stronger result and the proof is easier. The result we will prove is that $$x^2+x+1 \text{ divides }x^{n+1} + (x+1)^{2n-1}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Setting $x=11$ gives the result, you are looking for.

The proof follows immediately from the remainder theorem since $(x^2+x+1) = (x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)$, where $\omega$ is the complex cube-root of unity.

(Remember that $(x-a)$ divides $f(x)$ if and only if $f(x) = 0$)

Plugging in $\omega$ in $x^{n+1} + (x+1)^{2n-1}$ gives us $$\omega^{n+1} + (\omega+1)^{2n-1} = \omega^{n+1} + (-\omega^2)^{2n-1} = \omega^{n+1} - \omega^{4n-2} = \omega^{n+1} - \omega^{3n} \omega^{n-2}\\
=\omega^{n+1} - 1 \times \omega^{n-2} = \omega^{n-2} \left( \omega^3 - 1\right) = 0$$

This gives us that $(x- \omega)$ divides $x^{n+1} + (x+1)^{2n-1}$.

Similarly, plugging in $\omega^2$ in $x^{n+1} + (x+1)^{2n-1}$ gives us $$\omega^{2n+2} + \left( \omega^2 + 1 \right)^{2n-1} = \omega^{2n+2} + (-\omega)^{2n-1} = \omega^{2n+2} - \omega^{2n-1}\\ = \omega^{2n-1} \left( \omega^3 - 1\right) = 0$$ This gives us that $(x- \omega^2)$ divides $x^{n+1} + (x+1)^{2n-1}$.

Hence, $(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2) = x^2 + x + 1$ divides $x^{n+1} + (x+1)^{2n-1}$.

Setting $x=11$ gives us the result you want i.e. $11^2 + 11 + 1 = 133$ divides $11^{n+1} + 12^{2n-1}$.

Note that the above result can also be proved by inducting on $n$.

Comment: Interesting approach! How did you come up with the hypothesis, i.e. that $x^2+x+1 \text{ divides }x^{n+1} + (x+1)^{2n-1}$? It's not something that strikes me as acutely obvious :S

Comment: @Milosz $11$ and $12$ are adjacent numbers and the $133$ is the what we get by setting $n=1$ i.e. $133 = 12^2 - 11$. Hence, if we want to generalize and replace $11$ by $x$, then $12$ becomes $x+1$ and $133 = (x+1)^2 - x = x^2 + x + 1$.

Answer (score 9):

You had $12^2\cdot 133m-12\cdot11^{n+1}-11^{n+3}$?  Then you were very close.  Next note that $$-12\cdot11^{n+1}-11^{n+3}=-12\cdot 11^{n+1}-11^2\cdot 11^{n+1}=-(12+11^2)\cdot 11^{n+1}=-133\cdot 11^{n+1}$$ is a multiple of $133$.

$133$ is special here because $133=12^2-11 =11^2+12 = 11\cdot 12+1$.  This generalizes to $m^2+m+1 = (m+1)^2-m = m(m+1)+1$, and $m^{n+1}+(m+1)^{2n-1}$ is divisible by $m^2+m+1$ when $m$ is an integer and $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: If I may ask, why did you feel it was necessary to CW this?

Comment: It wasn't necessary, I just felt like it.  Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 9):

We try to explain how to arrive *mechanically* at a calculation that works.

Let $P_{k}=11^{k+1} +12^{2k-1}$.  Suppose that we know that $133$ divides $P_n$. We want to show that $133$ divides $P_{n+1}$.

**If** this is true, then $133$ must divide  $aP_{n+1}-bP_n$ for *any* integers $a$ and $b$.   Moreover, if we can find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $133$ divides $aP_{n+1}-bP_{n}$, **with** $a$ relatively prime to $133$, then we will know that $133$ divides $P_{n+1}$.

After all the semi-abstraction, let's do the details. We are looking at 
$$a\left(11^{n+2} +12^{2n+1}\right) -b\left(11^{n+1}+12^{2n-1}\right),\tag{$1$}$$
and want to choose $a$ and $b$ so that the expression $(1)$ is **simple** (and $a$ is relatively prime to $133$).  There are two obvious choices that simplify $(1)$ a lot. These are $a=1$, $b=11$ and $a=1$, $b=12^2$.  Each gives very pleasant cancellation.

Either choice works nicely. Let's use $a=1$, $b=12^2$. 
Then expression $(1)$ is equal to
$$11^{n+2}-(144)11^{n+1}.$$
But this simplifies to
$$11^{n+1}(11-144),$$
which certainly is divisible by $133$, so we are finished.

**Remark:** The above calculations were motivated by the *Euclidean algorithm* for calculating greatest common divisors, though one does not need to know this to use the procedure effectively.  Note that versions of the procedure can be used in a *mechanical* way for any problem with the same basic structure.

**Added:** Marvis has given a nice argument using cube roots of unity that  the polynomial $1+x+x^2$ divides $x^{n+1}+(1+x)^{2n-1}$. That can also be done by induction, with an argument that is insensitive to the underlying integral domain. In the language of the post above, choose $a=1$ and $b=(1+x)^2$. Then 
$$a\left(x^{n+2}+(1+x)^{2n+1}\right)-b\left(x^{n-1}+(1+x)^{2n-1}\right)$$
simplifies to $-(1+x+x^2)$, which is clearly divisible by $1+x+x^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the base case

For $n=1$,

$11^2+12^1=133$ is divisible by $133$.

Move from $k=n$ to $k=n+1$.

$$\eqalign{
  & {11^{n + 2}} + {12^{2n + 1}} = 11 \cdot {11^{n + 1}} + {12^2} \cdot {12^{2n - 1}} = 11 \cdot {11^{n + 1}} + \left( {133 + 11} \right) \cdot {12^{2n - 1}}  \cr 
  & 11 \cdot {11^{n + 1}} + 133 \cdot {12^{2n - 1}} + 11 \cdot {12^{2n - 1}} = 11 \cdot \left( {{{11}^{n + 1}} + {{12}^{2n - 1}}} \right) + 133 \cdot {12^{2n - 1}} \cr} $$

Thus it is true for all $n$.