# help solve $133| 11^{n+1} + 12^{2n-1}$ by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, exponential-function, divisibility

$$133|11^{n+1} + 12^{2n-1}$$
**I proof by Induction**

**Basic step**
$$
\begin{align}
P(1); 133|(121 + 12)
\end{align}
$$

**Inductive step**

$$
\begin{align}
P(k);&133|(11^{k+1}+12^{2k-1})\\ \\
P(k+1); & 11^{k+2} +12^{2k+1}\\ 
&(12-1)11^{k+2} + 12 ^{2k+1}\\
&12\cdot 11^{k+1} + 12 ^{2k + 1}\\
&12(11^{k+1}+12^{2k}) -11^{k+1}\\
&12(11^{k+1}+12^{2k-1}+11\cdot12^{2k-1})-11^{k+1}\\
&12(11^{k+1}+12^{2k-1}) + 11(12^{2k}-11^k)
\end{align}
$$
I can't solve more, please help!

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150979/show-that-11n1122n-1-is-divisible-by-133) is extremely similar

Comment: i think it must be $13$

Comment: Don't factor into a single product.   Break apart into a sum.  It's astonishingly easy to see $11^{n+1} + 12^{2n+1}= 11^{n} + 12^{2n-1} + 11 + 12^2 = 11^n + 12^{2n -1} +133$.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong! Try $n=1$, for which we need $1849$ is divisible by $133$.

If you mean to prove that $$11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}$$ is divisible by $133$ then we have:
$$11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}=121\cdot11^n+12\cdot144^n=12(144^n-11^n)+133\cdot11^n$$ and from here it's obvious because
$$144^n-11^n=(144-11)\left(144^{n-1}+...+11^{n-1}\right)$$
is divisible by $133$.

For your new problem we have:
$$11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}=11\cdot11^{n+1}+144\cdot12^{2n-1}=144(11^{n+1}+12^{2n-1})-133\cdot11^{n+1},$$
which ends the proof.

Comment: sorry , I was incorrect

Comment: @user490139 I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be $11^{n+1}+12^{2n-1}$ is divisible by $133$.

Base step is trivial.

Inductive step:
$$11^{k+2}+12^{2k+1}=11\times 11^{k+1}+144\times 12^{2k-1}$$
$$=11(11^{k+1}+12^{2k-1})+133\times 12^{2k-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is wrong. The problem should be $11^{n+1}+12^{2n-1}$ is divisible by $133$.