# Show that this expression is divisible by $133$ [more info in desc.]

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, integers

I'm sorry, but I just cannot figure this out to save my life. I need to show that the expression:

$$144*11^{n+1}+11*12^{2n-1}$$

is divisible by $133$ for all integers $n\geq 1$.  How would I do this?

Comment: if $n=0$ it is not a natural number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $11^{n+1}+12^{2n-1}$ is divisible by $133$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150979/show-that-11n1122n-1-is-divisible-by-133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider $\pmod{133}$

$$144\cdot11^{n+1}+11\cdot12^{2n-1} \equiv 11^{n+2}-12^{2n-2}\equiv 11^{n+2}-(12^2)^{n-1}\equiv11^{n+2}-11^{n-1}$$

$$\equiv 11^{n-1}\cdot(11^3-1)= 1330\cdot 11^{n-1}\equiv 0$$

Answer (score 2):

if $n\geq 1$, then
$$144*11^{n+1}+132*144^{n-1}=11^{n+2}-11^{n-1}=(1331-1)*11^{n-1}=0$$
where everything is considered modulo $133$.

Answer (score 2):

$144=11$ mod $133$, $11*12^{2n-1}=11*12*({12^2})^{n-1}=132*(144)^{n-1}=132*11^{n-1}$, this implies that $144*11^{n+1}+11*12^{2n-1}=11^{n+2}+132*11^{n-1}$ mod $133$

$=11^{n-1}(11^3+132)=0$ mod $133$