# Where can I read the rules on the algabraic manipulation needed to finish this inductive proof that $133$ divides $11^{k+1}+12^{2k-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, divisibility

Prove: 133 | $11^{k+1}$ + $12^{2k-1}$ , $\forall$ k > 0 
Basis: Let k = 1 
 133 | $11^{2}$ + $12^{1}$ $\implies$ 133 | 133, True 
Hypo: Assume true for k = n 
133 | $11^{n+1}$ + $12^{2n-1}$ 
Need to Prove: k = (n+1) 
133 | $11^{(n+1)+1}$ + $12^{2(n+1)-1}$ 
 $\implies$
133 | $11^{n+2}$ + $12^{2n+2-1}$ 
 $\implies$
133 | $11$($11^{n+1}$) + $12^2$($12^{2n-1}$) 
??? 
I know that by the hypothesis, 133 divides what is in the parenthesis, and that $11+12^2$ is also divisible by 133, but how can I manipulate the equation to make it so? If you guys can refer me to where I can read about this, or explain to me how and why, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150979/show-that-11n1122n-1-is-divisible-by-133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$11^{(n+1)+1} + 12^{2(n+1)-1} = 11 \cdot 11^{n+1} + 144 \cdot 12^{2n-1} = 11 \left(11^{n+1} + 12^{2n-1}\right) + 133 \cdot 12^{2n-1}$$

---

- $11 \left(11^{n+1} + 12^{2n-1}\right)$ is divisible by 133 by the induction hypothesis.
- $133 \cdot 12^{2n-1}$ is clearly a multiple of $133$.

Answer (score 0):

By the induction hypothesis, you know that $133|11^{n+1} + 12^{2n-1}$, meaning that for some integer $k$, you have that 
$$133k = 11^{n+1} + 12^{2n-1}$$
or equivalently 
$$12^{2n-1} = 133 - 11^{n+1}.$$
PLug this into you last expression you obtained and you'll find
$$11(11^{n+1}) + 12^2(133 - 11^{n+1})$$
and after rewriting:
$$133(12^2) + 11^{n+1}(11 - 12^2)$$
and $11 - 12^2 = 11-144 = -133$.